# Tensorflow no attribute 'no_automatic_dependency_tracking'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have verified that Tensorflow (version 2.5.0) is installed but get

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__.tracking' has no attribute 'no_automatic_dependency_tracking'
```

I have tried to find if an older version is needed and researching how to fix this but am finding little information on this particular attribute.

Comment: same issue here

Comment: Has anyone find a solution to this error??

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, you can't find what you're looking for because it's a method, you can find more about it in the [github repo for tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py). Just go to where the method is defined.